# How create resource id without a resource

Tags: android, android-resources

I need to associate several tags to a view so I use

```
 view.setTag(id, tag_object)
```

Unfortunately Android requires to have the id as defined in a resource. However R file is auto generated of resource ids appearing in different resource files, so I do not know how to create an id detached from any resource. As work around I just use id of some resource but it isn't robust, because if I decide to remove the resource, the id can disappear. It is also reduces readability of the code having some weird id for addressing a tag. Perhaps I missed very simple trick as ids resource file.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is a resource type "id" that lets you define arbitrary resource IDs:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="foo"/>
    <item type="id" name="bar"/>
</resources>
```

Will generate `R.id.foo` and `R.id.bar`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare Strings in your strings.xml file and use those id's. For readability purpose give them some good names. And don't use these strings somewhere else in your code or resources.